What’s the heaviest possible atomic nucleus?
What’s the heaviest theoretically possible atomic nucleus (highest element number) that can possibly be said to “exist”, such that if one single additional nucleon were added it would collapse into a black hole?
Assume you are able to place each nucleon on shell in place instantaneously in total violation of Heisenberg.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star

If you will, a neutron star is basically one giant nucleus consisting (almost) entirely of neutrons. This is crucial, since at these scales the coulomb repulsion between protons massively outweighs the weak force keeping your hypothetical nucleus together. That's what you should look for when investigating instabilities of high-$Z$ nuclei, not black hole formation.

So I guess that puts the heaviest possible atomic nucleus at around $10^{57}$ neutrons, or about 2 solar masses.

As pointed out in the excellent answer below, a neutron star is most definitely not a giant nucleus. A neutron star is held together by gravity, whereas a nucleus is held together by the strong force -see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus

The question is confusing. Mentioning blackholes is going to get neutron star as an answer, but that is not an atomic nucleus...even though it is nuclear matter, mostly neutrons with some protons and electrons too.
If you're talking about nuclei, then you need to define stable. Absolute stability is $^{208}\rm Pb$, but nuclei that last long about on nuclear time scales, may be considered stable in some circles. (That time scale is the time it takes light to cross the nuclear diameter).
The heaviest known isotope is $^{294}\rm Og$ (and no, Og does not stand for "O.G."). It has a 0.7 ms lifetime...pretty long. Light goes 70,000 feet in that time.
If you're interested in the limits of stability, see the drip lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_drip_line Various government websites have details on the table of nuclides:

The websites will be interactive.
Finally, the comment about plopping a nucleon into shell without regard to the HUP indicates you have a misunderstanding of what a nuclear shell, or nucleus in general, looks like. It's not this:

E.g., irl $^{12}\rm C$ is spin-zero and isospin-zero, so it is spherically symmetric, and uniformly proton and neutron. Each nucleon is entangled in something like $|pn\rangle - |np\rangle$, but more complicated, since there are 12 of them in total.
